# Mapreduce on GAE Python - Cause ReducePipeline to issue callback on finalize?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'd like to execute a custom callback function once a mapreduce job has finalized/completed.

The only useful references I found for this problem are [a somewhat outdated Google site](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/UserGuidePython) and a related, but again seemingly outdated [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114882/how-to-pass-a-google-mapreduce-parameter-to-done-callback).

Both those sources assume that I use `control.start_map` to kick off Mapreduce jobs, and rely on the fact that `start_map` takes a keyword argument `mapreduce_parameters` in which one can specify a `done_callback` argument to specify the url which should be called on completion. However, I'm using a different method (afaik the more recent, preferred one) in which a custom pipeline's `run` method yields a Mapreduce pipeline:

```
yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
    "word_count",
    "main.word_count_map",
    "main.word_count_reduce",
    "mapreduce.input_readers.BlobstoreZipInputReader",
    "mapreduce.output_writers.BlobstoreOutputWriter",
    mapper_params={
        "blob_key": blobkey,
    },
    reducer_params={
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
    },
    shards=16)
```

The signature for MapreducePipeline doesn't allow for a `mapreduce_parameters` argument. The only places where I can see references to callback cropping up in the source is in `mapper_pipeline.MapperPipeline.run`, but it seems to be used internally only.

So, is there a way to get that callback parameter in there?

If not, does someone have good ideas on where and how to extend the library to provide such a functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up my Mapreduce pipeline paradigm to look a little like the following:

```
class MRRecalculateSupportsPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self, user_key):
        # ...
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline('user_recalculate_supports',
                'myapp.mapreduces.user_recalculate_supports_map',
                'myapp.mapreduces.user_recalculate_supports_reduce',
                'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader', output_writer_spec=None,
                mapper_params={"""..."""})
```

If you would like to capture the completion of this pipeline you have two options.

A) Use pipeline.After to run a completion pipeline after the MR pipeline completes.

```
        pipe_future = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline('user_recalculate_supports',
                'myapp.mapreduces.user_recalculate_supports_map',
                'myapp.mapreduces.user_recalculate_supports_reduce',
                'mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader', output_writer_spec=None,
                mapper_params={"""..."""})
        with pipeline.After(pipe_future):
            yield CalcCompletePipeline(...)  # this could be a mapreduce pipeline, or any pipeline using the same base_handler.PipelineBase parent class.
```

B) Use the `finalized` method of the top-level pipeline to handle completion. Personally, I'd stick with option A, because you can trace the path in `/_ah/*/status?root=` view.

```
class EmailNewReleasePipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    """Email followers about a new release"""
    # TODO: product_key is the name of the parameter, but it's built for albums ...

    def run(self, product_key, testing=False):
            # Send those emails ...
            yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(...)

    def finalized(self):
        """Save product as launched"""
        ...
        product.launched = True
        product.put()
```

Here are the docs on the [finalization of a pipeline](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Finalization_of_pipelines).

Comment: Do you know what exactly pipeline.After does or why it is neceesay? In my experience, simply yielding the postprocessing pipeline will execute its code after finalization of the main pipeiline. That's also how the ouput file blobkey in the [GAE MR Hello World app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/helloworld) is retrieved, so I thought nothing of it.

Comment: pipeline.After is required to ensure the proper execution order of pipelines that are yielded. By far one of my favorite Pipeline functionalities, in the docs: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Execution_ordering

Answer (score 0):

At least a not-so-much-investment workaround for this issue is to simply yield another Map/Mapreduce pipeline that does the desired postprocessing.

E.g.:

```
class MainPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self):
        mapper_params = { ... }
        reducer_params = { ... }
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapReducePipeline(
            ...,
            mapper_params=mapper_params,
            reducer_params=reducer_params)
        yield PostprocessPipeline(reducer_params)


class PostprocessPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, reducer_params):
        do_some_postprocessing(reducer_params)
```

That workaround doesn't have access to the Mapreduce state, which I suppose could somehow be retrieved from the pipeline ID, but it's not yet obvious to me how. So, you'll have to set another flag/memcache/ds entry to check if the pipeline was completed successfully or not (if that's relevant to the postprocessing).

Comment: Using memcache for that purpose is worrysome - there is never any guarantee that the results will be available. I agree with the idea of yielding another pipeline, however. One thing that's definitely missing above is using with `pipeline.After((yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapReducePipeline...`